# php paypal returns INVALID on live

Tags: php

So I am working on a small site which takes a single payment per user.

When I do payments through the sandbox, if the payment is a success then i always get a IPN response and am able to use that to update my DB

BUT when using live even if paypal says it was a success the IPN returns INVALID
I have looked around for an answer and people have been saying make sure you are using paypal.com and not sandbox.paypal.com, I have done all the suggestions but still no luck.

A working answer to this would be much appreciated!

Here is my code:

This is the html form:

```
<form class="paypal" action="payments.php" method="post" id="paypal_form" target="_blank">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="UK" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Customer's First Name"  />
                    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Customer's Last Name"  />
                    <input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="customer@example.com"  />
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123456" / >
                    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo $invoice ?>" / >
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Payment Process"/>
                </form>
```

This code starts the payment:

```
<?php
// Database variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "un";
$password = "pw";
$dbname = "dbn";

// PayPal settings
$paypal_email = 'email@email.com';
$return_url = 'http://domain.co.uk/paypal/test.php';
$cancel_url = 'http://domain.co.uk/paypal/payment-cancelled';
$notify_url = 'http:/domain.co.uk/paypal/test.php';

$item_name = 'Item Name';
$item_amount = 1.00;
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];

// Include Functions
include("functions.php");

// Check if paypal request or response
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){
    $querystring = '';

    // Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
    $querystring .= "?business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";

    // Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html

    //The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";
    $querystring .= "invoice=".urlencode($invoice)."&";

    //loop for posted values and append to querystring
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
    }

    // Append paypal return addresses
    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url);

    // Append querystring with custom field
    //$querystring .= "&custom=".USERID;

    // Redirect to paypal IPN
    header('location:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
    exit();
} else {
    //Database Connection
    $link = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db($db_name);

    // Response from Paypal

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['item_name']          = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id']             = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom']             = $_POST['custom'];

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {
        // HTTP ERROR

    } else {
        fputs($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

                // Used for debugging
                // mail('user@domain.com', 'PAYPAL POST - VERIFIED RESPONSE', print_r($post, true));

                // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)
                $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
                $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
                // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
                if ($valid_txnid && $valid_price) {

                    $orderid = updatePayments($data);

                    if ($orderid) {
                        // Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database
                        mail("email@email.com","Success","Payment made successfully");
                        echo "updated";
                    } else {
                        // Error inserting into DB
                        // E-mail admin or alert user
                         mail('email@email.com', 'PAYPAL POST - INSERT INTO DB WENT WRONG', print_r($data, true));
                    }
                } else {
                    // Payment made but data has been changed
                    // E-mail admin or alert user
                }

            } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

                // PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY!
                // E-mail admin or alert user

                // Used for debugging
                //@mail("user@domain.com", "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Invalid Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");
            }
        }
    fclose ($fp);
    }
}
?>
```

This code handles the response from paypal:

```
<?php
// STEP 1: read POST data
// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
    $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
  $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
  if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  } else {
    $value = urlencode($value);
  }
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if ( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
  // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
  curl_close($ch);
  exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

// inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
  // The IPN is verified, process it
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
  // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
}

// inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
  // The IPN is verified, process it:
  // check whether the payment_status is Completed
  // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
  // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
  // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
  // process the notification
  // assign posted variables to local variables
  $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
  $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
  $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
  $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
  $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
  $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
  $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
  $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
  $invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
  // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
  // To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:

  foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " = " . $value . "<br>";

  }
    echo $res;

} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
  // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
  echo "Error! Paypal stated payment as: <b>" .$res ."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you summarize the differences in your code when you switch between sandbox and live? Also, can you give us more info on the response when it comes back INVALID? Seems to me paypal should be providing error information -- either directly in the response or otherwise via a dashboard when you login to their site. I would also point out that if you are submitting payments to the live (not sandbox) site, then you should also be attempting to verify the incoming IPNs by posting them back to the live (not sandbox) site.

Comment: @S.Imp When swtiching between sandbox and live changed any paypal urls from www.sandbox.paypal.com to www.paypal.com When running Live the IPN returns 200 - OK but a response of INVALID

Comment: Which returns INVALID? The initial payment attempt or the IPN script?

Comment: @S.Imp The IPN script, paypal says the payment was successful but when returning to my site and running through the IPN logic we get a return of INVALID

Comment: I've looked at your code pretty closely and I don't see anything that jumps out at me. A couple of things: would any of your data points (e.g., username, custom value, product_id) have an equal sign (=) or ampersand (&) in them? These might cause key-pairs to get dropped. I'd also suggest that you login to the paypal site and sniff around for any log functionality they offer. They may have an error log to tell you why your IPN-verify posts are getting rejected. They also offer this which looks like it has good advice: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/

Comment: Sadly, I can't be much more help without more info. You'll probably need to start logging the stuff that is showing up in your IPN script to a file (file_put_contents) and inspecting it closely. Maybe put log commands in there if anything weird happens, like **count($keyval) != 2**. Also, there's not much point in echoing anything from your IPN script -- this file is requested by the paypal website. The trick is to get paypal to request it over and over so you can log/test/debug.